# How to group by two columns in different CASE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that's giving me the results I want, but for each item with a given ID_UNIDAD_EXPERIMENTAL there are two rows, one with column "Alt" with a value and column "Dap" with null, and the other one with "Alt" null and "Dap" with a value.
My question is: How can I group them so each element with a given ID just shows both Alt and Dap columns with values, kind of "removing" the nulls.

Heres the query:

```
SELECT ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental,
    CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('alt') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END as alt,
    CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('dap') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END as dap
FROM ENS_Medicion 
JOIN ENS_Variable_medicion ON ENS_Variable_medicion.id_variable_medicion = ENS_Medicion.id_variable_med 
JOIN Variable_simple ON Variable_simple.id_variable_simple = ENS_Variable_medicion.id_variable_simple
join ENS_Variable_medicion varmed on ENS_Medicion.id_variable_med = varmed.id_variable_medicion
join Variable_simple vs on varmed.id_variable_simple = vs.id_variable_simple 
join ENS_Medicion_resumen mr on mr.id_medicion_resumen = ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen
where mr.nro_medicion = 3 and mr.id_ensayo = 9227 and (UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('alt') or UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('dap'))
GROUP BY ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental, Variable_simple.nombre, valor_medido, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental
ORDER BY id_unidad_exprimental
```

and here are the results:

[image: query results]

you can see that there are two rows for each "id_unidad_experimental" and each row has one column with a null value, the goal is to only show one row for "id_unidad_experimental" with the two values.

Any help would be nice

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: An you need to provide a [mre] i.e. showing us the data that produces those results. And ideally simplifying the problem does to the bare basics.

Comment: Read your question again and imagine you have no specific knowledge of your schema. You refer to " column "A" " and " column "B" " yet your code has no such columns. Do you see how that might be confusing? Do you also see the assumption in your post - only one of those two columns is not null? Is that guaranteed by constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like:

```
WITH cte as(
SELECT ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental,
        CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('alt') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END as alt,
        CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('dap') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END as dap
    FROM ENS_Medicion 
    JOIN ENS_Variable_medicion ON ENS_Variable_medicion.id_variable_medicion = ENS_Medicion.id_variable_med 
    JOIN Variable_simple ON Variable_simple.id_variable_simple = ENS_Variable_medicion.id_variable_simple
    join ENS_Variable_medicion varmed on ENS_Medicion.id_variable_med = varmed.id_variable_medicion
    join Variable_simple vs on varmed.id_variable_simple = vs.id_variable_simple 
    join ENS_Medicion_resumen mr on mr.id_medicion_resumen = ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen
    where mr.nro_medicion = 3 and mr.id_ensayo = 9227 and (UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('alt') or UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('dap'))
    GROUP BY ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental, Variable_simple.nombre, valor_medido, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental
    ORDER BY id_unidad_exprimental)

select t1.id_medicion_resumen, t1.id_ensayo, t1.id_unidad_exprimental, t1.alt, t2.dap 
from cte t1
inner join cte t2 on t1.id_medicion_resumen = t2.id_medicion_resumen and t1.id_ensayo = t2.id_ensayo and t1.id_unidad_exprimental = t2.id_unidad_exprimental
where t1.alt is not null 
and t2.dap is not null
```

Comment: This works, too, and its a little faster than Gordon Linoff's answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I used derived table of your result to get the output. But unfortunately I cannot test the result.  Better if you can give some sample data.

```
  SELECT    DISTINCT    A.id_medicion_resumen
        , A.id_ensayo
        , A.id_unidad_exprimental
        , MAX(alt) OVER ( Partition BY  A.id_unidad_exprimental ORDER BY A.id_medicion_resumen)  AS Alt
        , MAX(dap) OVER ( Partition BY  A.id_unidad_exprimental ORDER BY A.id_medicion_resumen) AS DAP 
        FROM
      (
        SELECT ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental,
            CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('alt') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END as alt,
            CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('dap') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END as dap
        FROM ENS_Medicion 
        JOIN ENS_Variable_medicion ON ENS_Variable_medicion.id_variable_medicion = ENS_Medicion.id_variable_med 
        JOIN Variable_simple ON Variable_simple.id_variable_simple = ENS_Variable_medicion.id_variable_simple
        join ENS_Variable_medicion varmed on ENS_Medicion.id_variable_med = varmed.id_variable_medicion
        join Variable_simple vs on varmed.id_variable_simple = vs.id_variable_simple 
        join ENS_Medicion_resumen mr on mr.id_medicion_resumen = ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen
        where mr.nro_medicion = 3 and mr.id_ensayo = 9227 and (UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('alt') or UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('dap'))
        GROUP BY ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental, Variable_simple.nombre, valor_medido, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental
        ORDER BY id_unidad_exprimental

    ) AS A
```

Comment: @SebastiánMatus you can do this in different ways. Please check and let me know whether you get your desired output

Comment: Yes! it did work, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer. I can see you have accepted some other answer. Thanks @SebastiánMatus

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation functions and fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental,
       MAX(CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('alt') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END) as alt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN UPPER(Variable_simple.nombre) = UPPER('dap') THEN CONVERT(decimal(18,7), ISNULL(NULLIF(valor_medido, ''), '0')) END) as dap
. . .
GROUP BY ENS_Medicion.id_medicion_resumen, mr.id_ensayo, ENS_Medicion.id_unidad_exprimental
```